# After parsing json file text is not printing

Tags: android, json

I have a php file at http://omnicoders.in/test/index.php that contain json data. I was trying to parse the file and print in textview. But when this file is executed nothing get printed. I wonder if there is some problem with parsing or with index.php as i am using it for first time.

```
    package com.example.connectingapp;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ConnectingMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connecting_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_intro);
    String url = getString(R.string.url);
    new Execution().execute(url);

}

class Execution extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        String overAll = "";

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lasr");
            String mail = jsonObject.getString("mail");
            overAll = name + " " + lastName + "\n" + mail;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return overAll;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result);
    }

}

   }
```

Comment: Post your stack trace. It would appear that you have an exception in the `try` block. Is `jsonObject.getString("lasr")` supposed to be `"last"`?

Comment: no its lasr only. and program is also running but just not showing text.

Comment: Are you sure it's running the entire `try` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your JSON data there is no tag with `name` actually i.e `first`. change your code to get the name from JSONObject like this it will work.

```
String name = jsonObject.getString("first");    // main change here 
String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lasr");
String mail = jsonObject.getString("mail");
overAll = name + " " + lastName + "\n" + mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its working. if the ws dose not have input data then do not use HttpPost

```
String url = "http://omnicoders.in/test/index.php";
        new Execution().execute(url);


class Execution extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                String overAll = "";

                try {


                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;

                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                            out.close();

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(out.toString());

                            String firstName = jsonObject.getString("first");
                            String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lasr");
                            String mail = jsonObject.getString("mail");
                            overAll = "Name: "+firstName + " " + lastName + "\nEmail:" + mail;
                        } else{
                            //Closes the connection.
                            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        //TODO Handle problems..
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //TODO Handle problems..
                    }
                    return overAll;



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                return overAll;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
               Log.e("Result:", result);
            }
```

07-04 04:48:13.745: E/Result:(1404): Name: vinit chouhan
07-04 04:48:13.745: E/Result:(1404): Email:vinit.gbps@gmail.com